# when launching terminal macos get error Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-m1, iterm

When first launch the termainal always get this error.

```
objc[9318]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c11eb0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d984f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[9318]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c11f00) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d98548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[9318]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c11f50) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d98598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[9318]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c11fa0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d985e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[9318]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c11ff0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d98638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[9318]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207c12040) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x103d98688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2022-03-15 19:51:39.868 xcodebuild[9318:34818] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-03-15 19:51:39.869 xcodebuild[9318:34818] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

Comment: Facing the Issue with MacOS 12.3 and Xcode 13.3 too - no clue how to resolve it at the moment

Answer (score 32):

Apparently it can be fixed using `sudo xcode-select -r`

I saw it twice but I don't know how to reproduce manually, or maybe I fixed it, I don't know.

Sources

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698628
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252824300?answerId=252824300021#252824300021

Comment: it didn't worked(

Comment: This on its own didn't work but installing xcode 12.3 and then running this worked for me. I think this started for me when I updated my OS and the xcode command line tools but didn't grab the matching version of xcode. Not 100% on that though

Comment: Does NOT work for me.

Answer (score 26):

Neither "installing components" via Xcode, nor resetting the developer directory using `sudo xcode-select -r` worked for me. However,

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

worked. Thanks to [Royite on Apple's Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698628?answerId=707435022#707435022) for this solution.

Comment: I've never had to run this pointing to CommandLineTools in all the years using Xcode but the second time I ran into this issue using this path fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Open XCode, it will prompt you to install some missing components.

Answer (score 5):

On my 12.2.1, the error disappears after "installing component" from Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

Remove CommandLineTools

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Reinstall CommandLineTools

```
xcode-select --install
```

Select CommandLineTools

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: you should know, I kissed the upvote button, not clicked ! :D thank you :D